# Time Machine fails to delete older backups on a network-attached volume

Tags: time-machine, smb, nas

I have a TrueNAS server set to expose an SMB share (configured with the *multi-user Time Machine* template) and (now) ACLs allowing all actions (including read/write/modify/delete) on that volume for the account I'm using to authenticate and do backups.

For some reason, whenever this volume runs out of space (which happens as a result of Time Machine itself — it's the only tenant on there), Time Machine just complains that it's full rather than deleting older backups. If memory serves, this used to be a toggle in System Preferences, but it looks like at some point the Time Machine preference pane got slimmed down pretty aggressively.

The volume isn't massive, but it's still double the hard drive size of the machine being backed up, so there's some breathing room.

Is there still a way to get Time Machine to delete older backups automatically?